# has_many relationship, accepts_nested_attributes_for - nested record not created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to create a relation_level, with a score attribute, for each interest_question/feed pair.  I am doing this with an accepts_nested_attributes_for :relation_levels in the feed form.  Everything renders as it should, and when the form is submitted, a feed is created, but no relation_levels are created.

I've also tried adding the feed_id as a hidden field in the form.

(using rails 4 and haml)

app/models/interest_question.rb

```
    class InterestQuestion < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :relation_levels, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :interest_answers, dependent: :destroy
    end
```

app/models/relation_level.rb

```
    class RelationLevel < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :feed
      belongs_to :interest_question
    end
```

app/models/feed.rb

```
    class Feed < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :relation_levels, dependent: :destroy
      has_many :interest_questions, through: :relation_levels

      accepts_nested_attributes_for :relation_levels
    end
```

app/views/feeds/_form.html.haml

```
      =form_for(@feed) do |f|            

        ...other fields
        ...other fields

        -@interest_questions.each do |iq|
          =f.fields_for @feed.relation_levels.build(interest_question_id: iq.id) do |rl|

            =rl.label iq.question_text
            =rl.range_field :score, max: 100, min: 0, default: 0
        =f.submit
```

app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb

```
    class FeedsController < ApplicationController
      def new
        @feed = Feed.new
        @sources = Source.all
        @interest_questions = InterestQuestion.all
      end

      def create
        @feed = Feed.new(feed_params)
        if @feed.save
          redirect_to '/feeds', notice: 'Feed created.'
        else
          render action: 'new'
        end
      end
      ...
      private

      def feed_params
        params.require(:feed).permit(..., relation_levels_attributes: 
                                     [:interest_question_id, :score, :feed_id])
      end
```

Server output:

`Started POST "/feeds" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-12-30 15:00:58 -0600
Processing by FeedsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"/+TOOdpZZk85YvVlxkRIpLNfPfVVtGUTlKPb9Ctkvh8=", "feed"=>{"url"=>"lkas6df.com", "source_id"=>"1", "section"=>"kasl6d6fa", "area_importance"=>"", "is_local_news"=>"0", "relation_level"=>{"score"=>"17"}}, "commit"=>"Create Feed"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."remember_token" = '6fcabf7c7b1376250b1ffa589ff4f2279854d066' LIMIT 1
Unpermitted parameters: relation_level
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  Source Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "sources".* FROM "sources" WHERE "sources"."id" = ? ORDER BY "sources"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Feed Exists (0.2ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "feeds" WHERE "feeds"."url" = 'lkas6df.com' LIMIT 1
  SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "feeds" ("created_at", "section", "source_id", "updated_at", "url") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 30 Dec 2013 21:00:58 UTC +00:00], ["section", "kasl6d6fa"], ["source_id", 1], ["updated_at", Mon, 30 Dec 2013 21:00:58 UTC +00:00], ["url", "lkas6df.com"]]
   (170.8ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/feeds`

I've been stuck on this for a while, thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Have you permitted necessary attributes in your controller following `strong parameters` guidelines?

Comment: +1 to vee above. Show your controller code and the output of your web server. Even in development env Rails won't complain very loud about missing the parameter in the whitelist, and in production hardly at all. But in your web server logs you will see "unpermitted params..." somewhere near the output from the create action.

Comment: You guys are right, there is an 'Unpermitted parameters: relation_level' in the server output, however, I don't know what else I need to whitelist since I have permitted the :relation_levels_attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a comment, but it's too big:

---

Maybe this could be your issue?

```
 =f.fields_for @feed.relation_levels.build(interest_question_id: iq.id) do |rl|
```

This builds an ActiveRecord object on the fly, which IMO is bad practice. I'd build the object in the controller, and then call the object in the `f.fields_for`, like this:

```
#app/controllers/feeds_controller.rb
def new
     @feed = Feed.new
     @sources = Source.all
     @interest_questions = InterestQuestion.all

     @interest_questions.count.times do
         @feed.relation_levels.build
     end
end
```

You can then call:

```
=f.fields_for :relation_levels do |rl|
```

Much cleaner, and will likely help with your debugging!

Comment: That was all I had to change and it fixed it, thanks!